# HttpContext.Current.Session is null on some servers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I hope this is a simple question. I have never had to deal with this issue and don't know how to even begin.

I have developed a web application that my users install and run on their own web server.

I implemented a feature to allow their users to change the pw from the default pw. This works perfectly on almost all servers. However, I have a new customer that cannot use it.

The current approach follows these steps:

1. User logs in with the default pw
2. User is taken to a view where they must create a new pw (otherwise their account is suspended)
3. Upon a successful pw change, the user is taken to the home screen.

For most companies, this works as expected. However, on this one server `Membership.GetUser(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)` is always null because `Current` is null. If I run the application locally and connect to their db, it works as expected. But, if I run it on their servers (same code just on their server connected to the exact same db), this is null and the pw change fails.

What additional information do I need to provide for help with this issue?

UPDATE: Here is the code I am calling:
The script called when the button is pressed:

```
var $account = {
changePw: function (homeUrl, reset) {
    $(".ui-widget").css("display", "none");
    var newPw1 = $("#newPw1").val();
    var newPw2 = $("#newPw2").val()
    if (newPw1 != newPw2) {
        $("#pwDontMatch").css("display", "block");
    }
    else {
        var url = rootUrl + "Account/ChangePassword";
        var data = {
            oldPassword: $("#currPw").val(),
            newPassword: $("#newPw1").val(),
            reset: "false"
        };
        if (reset) {
            data = { newPassword: $("#newPw1").val(), reset: "true", userId: $("#userIdTxt").val() };
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success != null && data.success == "true") {
                    $("#changeSuccess").css("display", "block");
                    setTimeout(function () { document.location.href = homeUrl; }, 3000);
                }
                else {
                    $("#error").css("display", "block");
                    if (data.error != null) {
                        $("#errMsg").html(data.error);
                    }
                }
            },
            failure: function () {
                $("#error").css("display", "block");
            },
            type: "POST"
        });
    }
}
};
```

And the controller called by the script:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This can be called from the change password page or the reset password page
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="form"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ChangePassword(FormCollection form)
    {
        JsonResult jr;

        // ChangePassword will throw an exception rather
        // than return false in certain failure scenarios.
        try
        {
            bool changePasswordSucceeded;
                MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, true /* userIsOnline */) ??
                    Membership.GetUser(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
                if (currentUser != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        changePasswordSucceeded = urrentUser.ChangePassword(form["oldPassword"], form["newPassword"]);
                        if (changePasswordSucceeded)
                        {
                            currentUser.IsApproved = true;
                            Membership.UpdateUser(currentUser);

                            if (currentUser.ProviderUserKey != null)
                            {
                                var mxUser = new MxUser(currentUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString());
                                Session["User"] = mxUser;
                                jr = Json(new {success = "true"});
                            }
                            else jr = Json(new {success = "false",error = "Cannot find ProviderUserKey."});

                        }
                        else jr = Json(new{success = "false",error = "Cannot update the user password."});
                    }
                    catch
                    { jr = Json(new{success = "false",error = "Unexpected error in updating the user password."}); }
                }
                else jr = Json(new {success = "false", error = "Cannot find the user"});
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { jr = Json(new {success = "false", error = ex.Message}); }
        return jr;
    }
```

If nothing, what setting, config, etc would they need to change to allow this to work?

Comment: The only reason I know of why `HttpContext.Current` is null during request is using `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on asynchronous operations... Since your sample is strictly synchronous it is unlikely the cause...

Comment: Where is this line located `Membership.GetUser(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)`?

Comment: Check to see if the app runs under the appropriate settings (version of the framework, integrated mode vs classic mode)

Comment: It's impossible for `System.Web.HttpContext.Currrent.User.Identity.Name` to be null if `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` is null.  What should be happening is that you would get a NullReferenceException because you're trying to dereference a null Current to get the User object, and that should not allow the application to continue processing, unless you are catching and swallowing the exception.  As for why HttpContext.Current would be null, that depends on many factors.. such as, where exactly is this occurring?  Show us some actual code.

Comment: @Stilgar, we did verify that framework and mode matched our other servers.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, I have added the code for my script and controller.

Comment: So are you getting a NullReferenceException returned in your Jason error message?

Comment: I also don't understand your GetUser usage.. there is no reason for using the ?? operator there, as the two methods are identical (GetUser without the second parameter is identical to GetUser with the second parameter true).  For that matter, GetUser() with no parameter is identical to specifying the current User Name from HttpContext.Current.User.Identy with the second parameter true.

Comment: Also, does logging on work normally otherwise?  Is HttpContext.Current available normally at any other time after the user is logged in?  And finally, why are you specifying HttpContext.Current.User?  The Controller class has a User property already which you can access.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, because of the null, I am getting the json notice, but it handles the error.  I didn't realize the first and second GetUser were the same and both the same as just GetUser().  Yes logging on works normally on their machine. I don't know why Current.User was originally specified, another dev started this code and I just continued with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<system.webServer>
```

```
<remove name="Session"/>     
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition=""/>
```

add this configuration and make sure the  session setting has  InProc or SQL or ASP.NET state service